# Como hacer que un panda no omita ceros en datos de una columna

Tags: pandas

estoy llenando un panda con valores de un csv el cual contiene numeros de esta forma
**00000000006000000**
pero al leerlos el panda muestra lo siguiente
**6000000**
mi pregunta seria como hacer para que no omita ningun valor y poder extraer la cadena tal cual esta en el archivo

anexo codigo

```
df = pd.read_csv('Bases.csv',sep=",",header=0,keep_default_na=False)

print(df3)
```

datos del documento csv:

1,00000000006000000
1,00000000028800000
1,00000000002200000

1,00000000020700000

salida del panda:

0  1  6000000
1  1  28800000
2  1  2200000
3  1  20700000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que pandas está extrayendo los datos como si fuesen números. Te ofrezco dos soluciones:

A- Podrías leer los datos como una string en vez de un número utilizando el parámetro de tipo de dato (`dtype`) del método `read_csv`.

```
pd.read_csv('Bases.csv',sep=",",header=0,keep_default_na=False, dtype = str)
```

[Documentación relevante](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

B- Si sabes de cuántos caracteres (voy a llamar este número `N`) son las cadenas, agarrar cada `número` y formatearlo para que tenga los ceros al frente utilizando el método de las string: `zfill`

```
str(numero).zfill(N)
```

Comment: muchas gracias a prmera opcion me ayudo a la perfeccion